# Multi-player game with Django, what to use for the communication between server and client?

Tags: django, node.js, websocket, tornado, gevent-socketio

I am currently developing a mutil-player game with Django. You can consider the game as a chat room app. Each user can create room of maximum 8 players, wait for other users to join in and then start to play.

For this purpose, I googled around and found two possible solutions:

- One is using Django with gevent-socketio or tornado, here is the [github link](https://github.com/rlr/django-gevent-socketio-redis-chat-example)
- The other is using Django with nodejs, here is the [link](http://maxburstein.com/blog/realtime-django-using-nodejs-and-socketio/) to the tuto

I do not know which solution is more suitable in my case. Besides, I guess I need dynamically create websocket for each chat room, right?

Answer (score 0):

I think its best you use `node.js` with `socket.io`. Its really simple and fits perfect for your situation. You will have to associate each client uniquely, which `socket.io` does for you by generating a unique client id which you can check further to do what you want.

Here is a good example to get you started : http://udidu.blogspot.com/2012/11/chat-evolution-nodejs-and-socketio.html